# Data structures and libraries for high dimensional text analysis with R

Tags: r, text-mining, large-data

I am going to be using R for text analysis (mostly clustering, classification and some visualization) and was wondering what mechanisms R provides for handling high dimensional, sparse data sets. If I understand correctly, R does provide some packages (e.g., [matrix library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/)) for handling large and sparse matrices - which brings me to my question.

Specifically, I would like to know:

1. Which R libraries are most appropriate for storing and processing high dimensional sparse data? Just FYI, my data will fit into memory.
2. Do such libraries inter-operate with existing text analysis (clustering/classification) packages? Would I need to convert these sparse data structures to and from data frames if I need to text analysis? Wouldn't that add additional time overhead to the computations?

I am fairly new to R, so please excuse me if this sounds vague (or too general).

Comment: Any thoughts on this one? I will appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This does not help you? http://tiny.cc/ns73n
Moreover, you can install `sos` R package to search any function in R, by using `findFn()` function in the `sos` package.

Comment: Well the problem is that tm library does not scale well. RWeka provides access to only select WEKA functionality (no way to call WEKA feature selection methods, for example). I don't see any other packages that would let you do pre-processing on text data in a scalable fashion. And then there's always this question of how to store and process highly sparse data...

Answer (score 0):

A quick google for [R text analysis](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=R%20text%20mining) lead me to the following article in the Journal for Statistical Software from 2008:

[Text Mining Infrastructure in R](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v25/i05/paper)

I'm not sure what is in it exactly, and it might be a bit outdated, but it should be helpful...